# How to open a new tab in browser from a ctools modal form in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

I'm creating a module with differents forms. I have some forms which are modal forms using ctools.
On one of these modal forms i made a button to open a pdf on a new tab in my browser but it doesn't work.
I have a AJAX error.
This is my code:

```
function liste_apprenant_partenaire($js){
if ($js) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');

    $form_state = array(
            'ajax' => TRUE,             
    );

    $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('liste_apprenant_partenaire_form', $form_state);

    if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
            $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
    }

    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();
}
else {
    return drupal_get_form('liste_apprenant_partenaire_form');
}
}

function liste_apprenant_partenaire_form($form, &$form_state){


$form['pv-button'] = array(
        '#id' => 'pv-button',
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'PV',
        '#submit'=>array('pv_apprenant_partenaire_button_form_submit'),
        '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'target="_blank";return true;'),
);

return $form;   
}


function pv_apprenant_partenaire_button_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
require_once("sites/all/modules/print/lib/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

$node_session=node_load($_SESSION['nid_session']);

$type_formation=$node_session->field_type[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

$test=file_get_contents('sites/all/modules/multi_example/test.html');
$test=str_replace('+type_formation',"$type_formation",$test);

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($test);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream('my.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));

}
```

When i put the path of the node in my browser, it's worked fine because the form appears normally not as a modal form.
But i research the same result using a modal form. So i think there is a problem with AJAX but i don't find the real solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What does your error message look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and thank you for you help. i have a error message like this:  error HTTP AJAX, HTTP status code  : 200, StatusText: Ok, ReponseText: %PDF-1.3, 1 0 obj .... i think the content of the pdf which i created appaers in the error message. And i have tried to make a js file on my directory to replace the line `'#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'target="_blank";return true;'),` of the form['pv-button'] by `$(this).attr('target','_blank');` but it doesn't work. No error message but it does anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use button type submit
use form item type link then if you need this link look like button then you can style this as a button 
use like this in the form

```
$form['my_module_custom_link'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => 'PDF',
  '#href' => "/my/hello",
  '#attributes' => array(
    'target' => '_blank',
),
```

it should display a link inside the form then style it as you need